# How to fix mosquitto mid values?

Tags: mosquitto

I use the mosquitto mqtt broker and have a question about its message id (mid) values as follows.

I send a message to test channel that has a mid of "1234", but the PUBACK mid is printed as another value

I want to print mid "1234"

What do I need to modify in the mosquitto source?

```
1435417408: Received PUBLISH from adventures (d0, q1, r0, m1234, 'test', ... (5 bytes)) 
1435417408: Sending PUBLISH to myclientid_49 (d0, q1, r0, m3, 'test', ... (5 bytes)) 
1435417408: Sending PUBLISH to myclientid_20 (d0, q1, r0, m2, 'test', ... (5 bytes)) 
1435417408: Sending PUBACK to adventures (Mid: 1234) 
1435417408: Received DISCONNECT from adventures 
1435417409: Received PUBACK from myclientid_49 (Mid: 3) 
1435417409: Received PUBACK from myclientid_20 (Mid: 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Let me just go through your broker logs for you.

This line is your published message received from the `adventures` client. You can see `m1234` which is saying that the message id is 1234, like you said.

```
1435417408: Received PUBLISH from adventures (d0, q1, r0, m1234, 'test', ... (5 bytes))
```

These two lines show the message being sent to two clients that are subscribed to the `test` topic. They have message id `3` and `2` respectively. Note that message ids are handled separately for different clients and message directions.

```
1435417408: Sending PUBLISH to myclientid_49 (d0, q1, r0, m3, 'test', ... (5 bytes)) 
1435417408: Sending PUBLISH to myclientid_20 (d0, q1, r0, m2, 'test', ... (5 bytes))
```

This is the broker sending the PUBACK back to the original client. You'll see again that the message id is 1234.

```
1435417408: Sending PUBACK to adventures (Mid: 1234)
```

This is the disconnect message from the original client.

```
1435417408: Received DISCONNECT from adventures
```

And this is the subscribing clients sending a PUBACK back to the broker, repeating the mid `3` and `2` from above.

```
1435417409: Received PUBACK from myclientid_49 (Mid: 3) 
1435417409: Received PUBACK from myclientid_20 (Mid: 2)
```

In conclusion, I think it all makes sense.

Comment: makes sense a lot...Thanks